# How to get the path to the current theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, directory, paths

This code is used to get the directory of the current plugin: `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )`.

What should I use to get the directory of the current theme?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think you have to be a little careful because it depends on what you are trying to do.

If you are using a child theme `get_template_directory();` will still go to the parent theme.  However `get_stylesheet_directory();` will go to the current theme, child or parent. Also, both these functions return absolute server paths.

If you wanted a fully formed URI, for links or images, you should use `get_template_directory_uri();` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` using the correct one for the reasons stated.

#### Summary

- [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory): file path to current Theme directory
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri): url path to current Theme directory
- [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory): file path to parent Theme directory
- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri): url path to parent Theme directory

Comment: +1. *Always* use `stylesheet` filepath/url to reference the *current* Theme, and reserve `template` filepath/url to reference the *parent* Theme.

Comment: Unfortunately get_template_directory() returns the entire server path like `/var/www/the/path/of/actual/wp-content/themes/mytheme` which is not what you want for doing stuff with $wp_filesystem if WP is connecting through FTP.

Comment: @NoBugs - I was getting the entire server path as well but using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_stylesheet_directory() solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! most answers i found got me part of the way there with using get_stylesheet_directory() but then I was left in the root directory of my server. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() was the answer to my prayers! 

Comment: Ah, Wordpress. Backwards-compatible to a fault. (No sane person would deliberately use such ambiguous naming conventions!)

Answer (score 12):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri` is what you want. it returns the URL of the current theme. `get_stylesheet_directory` will return the file path on the server.

For example:

```php
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/image.png" />
```

If you need the parent theme, `get_template_directory` and `get_template_directory_uri` are the equivalents.

**If there is no parent theme then both will return the same value.**

Further reading:

- [`get_stylesheet_directory`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/)

  - absolute folder path of current theme
  - e.g. `/var/www/yoursite/wp-content/themes/child_theme`
- [`get_template_directory`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/)

  - absolute folder path of parent theme
  - e.g. `/var/www/yoursite/wp-content/themes/parent_theme`
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)

  - full URL of current theme
  - e.g. `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/child_theme`
- [`get_template_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

  - full URL of parent theme
  - e.g. `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/parent_theme`

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory()` is the correct answer. `get_template_directory()` will point to the parent theme if a child theme is being used.

Comment: I adjusted the answer accordingly