# get_template_directory vs get_stylesheet_directory

Tags: child-theme

I am trying to create a child theme and need to replace some files that are in sub-folders.

[In this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48128/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-current-theme), it states

> `'get_stylesheet_directory();` will go to the current theme, child or parent

Why don't theme developers just use `get_stylesheet_directory()` if it would work for the parent or child theme?

It seems that I now have to change every reference to `get_template_directory()` to get my child files to work (that are in sub-folders) or is there another way of doing this?

This post by [Andrew Nacin](http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/) states that,

> you can just replace files directly in a child theme.

But it seems that this only works for one level deep.

Is there a way for this to work with more than one level and would this be easier than changing each reference to `get_template_directory()`?

Comment: the two things are unrelated, the post you linked to is about the code that WordPress uses to search for [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) in a theme. `get_stylesheet_directory` just contains the path to the active theme, the rest of the path is up to you, so files can be replaced 100 directories deep if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

> Why don't theme developers just use get_stylesheet_directory if it
>   would work for the parent or child theme?

The answer is not complicated: "Because you may not want it to work for either the parent or a child theme."

You choose the function that fits the situation. For example, you have  a set of files in the parent theme that contain critical classes or functions. You use `get_template_directory()` because you ***don't want to allow*** the child to override/replace the files. It is the same reason you can't replace WordPress Core files or functions (in most cases).